# Oracle multitenant - change container from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, pdb

I have problem to change the container from PL/SQL.
The result are the same, either with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or with DBMS_SQL.
I login to the root as SYSDBA with a common user. I have one application root PDB inside, called PDB1

I am able to switch the container and get back with :

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER =PDB1;

alter session set container = CDB$ROOT;
```

but when I do ti from PL/SQL, I can go from the root to PDB1 , but , can not go back to the root:

```
begin

execute immediate 'alter session set container=PDB1';

end;
/
```

this works, I am now inside PDB1

if I now try to go back to the root with :

```
begin

execute immediate 'alter session set container=CDB$ROOT';

end;
/
```

I get an error:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

The similar results are with the application root PDB and its PDBs, with the common application user ...so, I can switch from the application root to PDBs, but can not go back.

Is there any way, or privilege, that I can switch to the upper container from PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained in [this WP](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/multitenant/learn-more/multitenant-security-concepts-12c-2402462.pdf) (top of page 11). In all cases, what are you trying to do? It is not really advisable to change containers inside PL/SQL, except in very special cases, like all you SQL code there is in fact dynamic.

Comment: ok, thx, I see now explicitly that it is not allowed. It is blocked from PDBs. In Particular, I want to execute the PL/SQL code incide another container, using DBMS_SQL. Its function PARSE has a parameter CONTAINER, but seems to be that the mentioned restriction also applied on this. Because I get the same error. And the reason why I want to execute PL/SQL inside another container is to put one message inside Advanced Queue that is defined on that other container....and I dont want to use db link and the message propagation to do that.......

Comment: Even in the WP that you shiwn here looks like DBMS_SQL would solve the problem....in my test case, with the application root and applciation common user, it fails with the same error message. So, in particular, I want to be able to execute DBMS_SQL.PARSE, from one PDB, that belongs to the application root, inside another PDB , that belongs to the same application root..using the common application user......

Comment: Allowing a user in one pdb to change container to another inside PL/SQL is a huge security loophole, as the PL/SQL code is compiled and checked security-wise in the original pdb. I think using AQ to exchange messages would be the best solution.

Comment: yes, I agree, but on the other hand, as I understand, DBMS_SQL.PARSE, with the parameter for CONTAINER is explicitly written to be able to execute PL/SQL block inside the another container. Plus, the PL/SQL block is then dynamically compiled and checked...I simplified this thread with the focus on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but, I am also fine with DBMS_SQL.PARSE...which, unfortunately has the same error.